# Scrapy web scraper not putting URLs and article titles scraped in to a csv file

Tags: python, web-scraping

Code is intended to scrape specific section of a news site and acquire the URLs of articles from the politics section. output shows that the URLs are being taken but none appear in the CSV file created to store both the URLs and the actual titles of the articles.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import csv
import re 


class News_Spider(scrapy.Spider):
  name="news_spider"

  def start_requests(self):
    url="https://www.irishtimes.com/politics/"
    yield scrapy.Request(url=url,callback=self.parse_front)

  
  def parse_front(self,response):
    #Code to parse Irish Times Politics Page
    date_reg_exp = re.compile('[-/]politics[-/]\d{4}[-/]\d{2}[-/]\d{2}')
    article_links = response.css('body>div a::attr(href)').extract()
    article_links_cleaned=[]
    #print("lalalala")
    print(article_links)
    for link in article_links:
      matches_list=date_reg_exp.findall(link)
      if len(matches_list)>0:
        link_to_add="https://www.irishtimes.com"+link
        if link_to_add in article_links:
          continue
        article_links_cleaned.append(link_to_add)
    for link_to_follow in article_links_cleaned:
      yield response.follow(url=link_to_follow,callback=self.get_title_politics_section)

  def get_title_politics_section(self,response):
    title = response.css("h1.article__heading::text").get()
    yield {"url": response.url, "title": title}
    pass

  def closed(self, reason):
    items = list(self.get_title_politics_section(None))
    with open("articles.csv", "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as file:
      fieldnames = ["url", "title"]
      writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
      writer.writeheader()
      for item in items:
        writer.writerow(item)

process=CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(News_Spider)
process.start()
```

Have tried few different methods for the finally two functions that are being used to write the the csv file but nothing working. not sure if the close function is not properly integrated with the spider function or not

Answer (score 0):

You can use scrapy cmd to have it done easily.

The code should be:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import csv
import re 


class News_Spider(scrapy.Spider):
  name="news_spider"

  def start_requests(self):
    url="https://www.irishtimes.com/politics/"
    yield scrapy.Request(url=url,callback=self.parse_front)

  
  def parse_front(self,response):
    #Code to parse Irish Times Politics Page
    date_reg_exp = re.compile('[-/]politics[-/]\d{4}[-/]\d{2}[-/]\d{2}')
    article_links = response.css('body>div a::attr(href)').extract()
    article_links_cleaned=[]
    #print("lalalala")
    print(article_links)
    for link in article_links:
      matches_list=date_reg_exp.findall(link)
      if len(matches_list)>0:
        link_to_add="https://www.irishtimes.com"+link
        if link_to_add in article_links:
          continue
        article_links_cleaned.append(link_to_add)
    for link_to_follow in article_links_cleaned:
      yield response.follow(url=link_to_follow,callback=self.get_title_politics_section)

  def get_title_politics_section(self,response):
    title = response.xpath("//h1[contains(@class, 'custom-headline')]/text()").get()
    yield {"url": response.url, "title": title}`
```

Then, you can run the spider and written it to a csv file by running the following command:

```
scrapy runspider so10.py -o articles.csv
```

Output example:

```
url,title
https://www.irishtimes.com/politics/2023/02/23/holly-cairns-front-runner-for-social-democrats-leadership-but-two-other-tds-may-contest-role/,Holly Cairns front-runner for Social Democrats leadership
https://www.irishtimes.com/politics/2023/02/23/improving-tax-treatment-for-landlords-a-good-idea-varadkar-says/,"Improving tax treatment for landlords a ‘good idea’, Varadkar says"
https://www.irishtimes.com/politics/2023/02/23/fianna-fails-support-down-since-martins-exit-from-taoiseachs-office/,Irish Times poll: Fianna Fáil’s support down since Martin’s exit from taoiseach’s office
https://www.irishtimes.com/politics/2023/02/23/irish-times-poll-reassurance-for-fine-gael-and-sinn-fein-but-a-bit-of-a-jolt-for-fianna-fail/,Irish Times poll: Reassurance for Fine Gael and Sinn Féin but a bit of a jolt for Fianna Fáil
https://www.irishtimes.com/politics/2023/02/22/ni-protocol-can-british-pm-rishi-sunak-cut-a-deal-acceptable-to-the-dup-and-eu/,NI protocol: Can British PM Rishi Sunak cut a deal acceptable to the DUP and EU?
https://www.irishtimes.com/politics/2023/02/23/irish-times-poll-all-to-play-for-when-it-comes-to-composition-of-next-government/,Irish Times poll shows there is still all to play for when it comes to composition of next government
https://www.irishtimes.com/politics/2023/02/23/irish-times-poll-sinn-fein-consolidates-place-at-top-of-political-pile/,Irish Times poll: Sinn Féin consolidates place at top of political pile
```

However, if you plan to run more scrapy spiders and you don't want to deal with running the spider manually you can use use [estela](https://github.com/bitmakerla/estela) which is a spider management solution developed by [Bitmaker](https://bitmaker.la/en/).